# How do I setup Internationalized Domain Names (IDNs) to display correctly in the browser URL bar?

Tags: idn, punycode

I just bought several Internationalized Domain Names (IDNs) from GoDaddy. I have a VPN with hostgator and when I add an account with WHM and then I go to that site with a link that has the IDN, it displays in the browser as the puny-code. How can I make the browser display the correct encoding, instead of the puny-code?

Comment: This will be dependent on client-side browser settings. Are you just wanting to do this for your own testing, or are you wanting to somehow configure your server/pages so that the nice IDN is displayed as intended in the browser for all users?

Comment: Yes, the latter.

Comment: You need to add a language to chrome that contains the suitable characters.

Answer (score 3):

The browser is showing the punny-code as a way to protect you from phishing sites.
There are several Unicode glyphs who are virtually indistinguishable one from another.

which is the good one?

```
microsoft.com
microsft.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Which web browsers have you tried and what tld(s) are the idn domains for?

Firefox supports IDN but only for some tld's - go to about:config in the firefox address bar and search for idn to see the list.

updated:

.ws isn't on firefox's whitelist, they have a page here:

http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/tld-idn-policy-list.html

That has links to there policy documents and details on how to get a tld added. You could enable IDN for .ws in your own copy of firefox by adding **network.IDN.whitelist.ws** with the value **true** to about:config.

That will only work for you of course...

Comment: I have tried Chrome, and the tld is .ws.

Comment: and I just tried Firefox. That doesn't work either. But Safari does work! It would be nice if they all did. This is on OSX btw.